# Tokenizer vs token filters

Tags: elasticsearch, token, tokenize

I'm trying to implement autocomplete using Elasticsearch thinking that I understand how to do it...

I'm trying to build multi-word (phrase) suggestions by using ES's edge_n_grams while indexing crawled data.

What is the difference between a `tokenizer` and a `token_filter` - I've read the docs on these but still need more understanding on them....

For instance is a token_filter what ES uses to search against user input? Is a tokenizer what ES uses to make tokens? What is a token?

Is it possible for ES to create multi-word suggestions using any of these things?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A tokenizer will split the whole input into tokens and a token filter will apply some transformation on each token.

For instance, let's say the input is `The quick brown fox`. If you use an edgeNGram **tokenizer**, you'll get the following tokens:

- `T`
- `Th`
- `The`
- `The` (last character is a space)
- `The q`
- `The qu`
- `The qui`
- `The quic`
- `The quick`
- `The quick` (last character is a space)
- `The quick b`
- `The quick br`
- `The quick bro`
- `The quick brow`
- `The quick brown`
- `The quick brown` (last character is a space)
- `The quick brown f`
- `The quick brown fo`
- `The quick brown fox`

However, if you use a standard tokenizer which will split the input into words/tokens, and then an edgeNGram **token filter**, you'll get the following tokens

- `T`, `Th`, `The`
- `q`, `qu`, `qui`, `quic`, `quick`
- `b`, `br`, `bro`, `brow`, `brown`
- `f`, `fo`, `fox`

As you can see, choosing between an edgeNgram **tokenizer** or **token filter** depends on how you want to slice and dice your text and how you want to search it.

I suggest having a look at the excellent [elyzer](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer) tool which provides a way to visualize the analysis process and see what is being produced during each step (tokenizing and token filtering).

As of ES 2.2, the `_analyze` endpoint also supports an [explain feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/_explain_analyze.html) which shows the details during each step of the analysis process.

Comment: I work with ES 1.7 and it produces different output than what this answer suggests. A number of tokens and tokens themselves are identical between tokenizer and filter: `t, th, the, q, qu, qui, ...` but offsets and positions are different. Filter: `{"token": "qui", "start_offset": 4,  "end_offset": 9,  "position": 2}`. Tokenizer: `{"token": "qui", "start_offset": 4, "end_offset": 7, "position": 6}`

Answer (score 7):

I want to publish some detailed use cases.

### Edge n-gram tokenizer (default)

By default this tokenizer treats all text as a single token because by default token can contain any characters (including spaces).

```js
GET {ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/_analyze

{
  "tokenizer": "edge_ngram",
  "text": "How are you?"
}
```

Result:

```js
["H", "Ho"]
```

Explanation: one token, `min_gram` = 1, `max_gram` = 2.

### Edge n-gram tokenizer (custom without token_chars)

```js
PUT {ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/custom_edge_ngram

{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_edge_ngram": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_edge_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 7
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
GET {ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/custom_edge_ngram/_analyze

{
  "analyzer": "custom_edge_ngram",
  "text": "How old are you?"
}
```

Result:

```js
["Ho", "How", "How ", "How o", "How ol", "How old"]
```

Explanation: still one token, `min_gram` = 2, `max_gram` = 7.

### Edge n-gram tokenizer (custom with token_chars)

```js
PUT {ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/custom_edge_ngram_2

{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_edge_ngram": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_edge_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 7,
          "token_chars": ["letter"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
GET {ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/custom_edge_ngram_2/_analyze

{
  "analyzer": "custom_edge_ngram",
  "text": "How old are you?"
}
```

Result:

```js
["Ho", "How", "ol", "old", "ar", "are", "yo", "you"]
```

Explanation: 4 tokens `How`, `old`, `are`, `you` (tokens can contain only letters because of `token_chars`), `min_gram` = 2, `max_gram` = 7, but max token length in the sentence is 3.

### Edge n-gram token filter

Tokenizer converts text to stream of tokens.

Token filter works with each token of the stream.

Token filter can modify stream by adding, updating, deleting its tokens.

Let's use `standard` tokenizer.

```js
GET {ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/_analyze

{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "text": "How old are you?"
}
```

Result:

```js
["How", "old", "are", "you"]
```

Now let's add token filter.

```js
GET {ELASTICSEARCH_URL}/_analyze

{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter": [
    { "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": 2,
      "max_gram": 7
    }
  ],
  "text": "How old are you?"
}
```

Result:

```js
["Ho", "How", "ol", "old", "ar", "are", "yo", "you"]
```

Explanation: `edge_nram` for each token.