# autocomplete and search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4, search

Is there any possibility to make a search on two non-complete words in the same field using `Elasticsearch in Rails`? I mean the situation when I could successfully search for example "`victorian buildings`" phrase by inserting into search input for example "`vict bui`" phrase (only beginnings of words, also with fuzziness).

Partial match (`word_start`, `text_start` etc. available in `Searchkick`) doesn't work in this project. I've also tried using wildcard queries, but it also failed. Maybe writing some custom mappings/settings would be a good idea?

Can I ask you for any suggestions on what to search/read to do this task?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168764/tokenizer-vs-token-filters/37169584#37169584 (hint: use a standard tokenizer with an edge-ngram token filter to tokenize prefixes of all tokens)

Comment: it helped me :) thank you

Comment: Can you update your question to explain why partial match doesn't work? `word_start` is designed for this use case.

Comment: this https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/ should help

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this example


"%#{params[:place]}%"


Since % is a wildcard, doing a like on '%%' matches everything,
```

and you get all the records in the result.