# Defined a edgeNGram, search works only on complete words, not tokens

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using es 6.4 as AWS service. Here is my mapping -

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "my_tokenizer": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 3,
        "max_gram": 20,
        "token_chars": [
          "letter"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tsetse": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "user_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The index has a record with description = "greatest performance on earth". When I try to search, it always works on complete word - earth or performance. Does not return results on great or perf. What am I missing?

Here is updated mapping with EdgeNGram `

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tsetse": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "user_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

Gist script - https://gist.github.com/swati-patil/0b1cea74fc52b1b96d44ad239ad2580d
Thanks,

Comment: I'm surprised you could even create your index, as the `tokenizer` section is not properly located, it should be located inside `analysis`

Comment: The problem is that you should not be using an `edge_ngram` **tokenizer** but an `edge_ngram` **token filter**: Here is the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168764/tokenizer-vs-token-filters/37169584#37169584

Comment: The link explains in great details. I did modify edge_ngram tokenizer to token filter. I still don't see the output. I must have been doing something seriously stupid.

Comment: Can you update your question with how your settings look like now?

Comment: @Val updated settings.

Comment: Looks good. Are you certain you've deleted your index and reindexed your data? On my end, using your settings, if I search for `great` or `perf` I do find the document. What do you get when running this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze -d '{"analyzer":"my_analyzer", "text": "greatest performance on earth"}'` ?

Comment: I did drop the index and recreate a new one. I'm using AWS managed service, and this is the output I get - {"_index":"my-index","_type":"tsetse","_id":"_analyze","found":false}

Comment: Sorry, use POST instead of GET, and don't specify the type `tsetse`, simply `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/my-index/_analyze ...`

Comment: Please provide a Gist so we can reproduce exactly what you're doing. Otherwise we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: Please provide a [gist recreation script](https://gist.github.com/) so that we can create the index, add documents and do some search from scratch. it's not legible in comments.

Comment: Updated comment with gist. Thanks much with your help.

Comment: In the second command, you have `analysnalysis`, instead of  `analysis` and you're not creating the index correctly, the command should be `curl -XPUT "my-instance-us-east1.amazonaws.com/my_index" -H ...` See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the Gist. I can see you're not creating your index correctly:

1. you're using POST instead of PUT
2. you're specifying a type where you shouldn't
3. there are two closing curly braces that you need to remove at the end

Do it like this instead:

```
# first delete your index
curl -XDELETE 'my-instance-us-east1.amazonaws.com/my_index'

# then create it correctly
curl -XPUT "my-instance-us-east1.amazonaws.com/my_index" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

# then analyze works
curl -XPOST my-instance-us-east1.amazonaws.com/my_index/_analyze -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "Greatest performance on earth"
}'
```

Then index your documents and run your queries, they will both work.